# Solr schema design and performance

Tags: solr

I have books database that has three entities: Books, pages and titles (titles found in a page). I have got confused and concerned about performance between two approaches in the schema design:

1- Dealing with books as documents i.e book field, pages field with multiValue and titles field with multiValue too. In this approach all of the book data will be represented in one Solr document with very large fields.

2- dealing with pages as documents which will lead in much smaller fields but larger number of documents.

I tried to look at [this official resource](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors) but I could not able to find a clear answer for my question.

Comment: Post a descriptions for each table and what you are planning to search on in Solr.

Comment: @orangepips It is simple, Book has many pages and then page has many titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are going to take Solr results and present them through another application, I would make the smallest item - Titles - the model for documents, which will make it much easier to present where a result appears. Doing it this way minimizes the amount of application code you need to write. If your users are querying Solr directly I might use Page as a my document instead - presumably you are using [Solr's highlighting feature](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) then to assist your users with identifying how their search term(s) matched.

For Title documents I would model the schema as follows:

1. Book ID + Page Number + Title [string - unique key]
2. Book ID [integer]
3. Book Name [tokenized text field]
4. Page Number [TrieIntField]
5. Title [tokenized text field]
6. Content for that book/title/page combination [tokenized text field]

There may be other attributes you want to capture, such as author, publication date, publisher, but you do not explain above what other information you have so I leave that out of this example.

Textual queries then can involve `Book Name`, `Title` and `Content` where you may want to define a single field that's indexed, but not stored, that serves as a target for `<copyField/>` declarations in your schema.xml to allow for easy searching over all three at the same time.

For indexing, without knowing more about the data being indexed, I would use the [ICU Tokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-ICUTokenizer) and [Snowball Porter Stemming Filter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-SnowballPorterStemmerFilter) with a language specification on the text fields to handle non-English data - assuming all the books are in the same language. And if English, the Standard Tokenizer instead of ICU.

Comment: Wonderful explanation, but, do you think that the schema layout you suggested will lead to semi-repeated documents?! Since, Page has many titles, so, if we have a page with three titles, we will get three documents with the same data except the title field. In this situation a large amount of identical data (content - Page contents I mean here) should be indexed three times. However, your analysis make me to adopt the second design I asked about in the question by making title multiValues field.

Comment: You will absolutely have semi-repeated documents, but that's the point of a search index as opposed to a relational database IMO: denormalize your data to make search easier.